# About autoreleasing a property

Tags: objective-c

**selectedSearchResult** is a class property.

I thought if I write

```
selectedSearchResult = [[[results lastObject] retain] autorelease];
```

the property is released only when the class instance is deallocated, but when I invoke selectedSearchResult, it is null in the next method.

Thanks

Comment: ref counter is still +1. What happens to results array? Is it released meanwhile?

Comment: @Kay results is a local variable and it should be autoreleased when method exits. It is created with a factory method (returning an autoreleased value) in the method scope.

Comment: So that's why I decided to retain and autorelease it again, but it seems not working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `selectedSearchResult` is a property, then call it as property

```
self.selectedSearchResult = [results lastObject];
```

Comment: ok thanks. I've now changed all assignments to the iVar to  property setters (as you suggested). But my app is still crashing, it is still a zombie in another method. I've some difficulties to debug it.

Comment: is your property declared as `retain`?

Comment: Ya. @property (nonatomic, retain) CCSearchResult *selectedSearchResult;

Comment: Sorry, it seems solved ya. It is still crashing but for another reason related to the change however. But answering to my question, the variable is not a zombie anymore.